# Как используя sqlalchemy query выбрать из таблицы запись с минимальным значением в стобце?

Tags: sql, orm, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

У меня есть связь "многие-ко-многим" организованная через промежуточную таблицу `uploads`:

```
uploads = db.Table('uploads',
    db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id')),
    db.Column('file_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('files.id')),
    db.Column('timestamp', db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow())
)
```

Хочу получить запись из таблицы с `file_id = my_custom_file_id` минимальным значением `timestamp` ?

Пока имеется след. запрос:

```
>>> db.session.query(uploads).filter_by(file_id = 1).all()
[(1, 1, datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 25, 10, 24, 29, 768315)), (2, 1, datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 25, 10, 26, 54, 12459))]
```

Что мне надо в нем улучшить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сходу думается, как-то так можно сделать:

```
query = session\
          .query(func.min(uploads.c.timestamp).label('min_timestamp'))\
          .filter(uploads.c.file_id==1)
min_timestamp = query.one().min_timestamp

query = session.query(uploads).filter_by(file_id=1, timestamp=min_timestamp)
print(query.all())
```

Comment: Ваш способ сработал путем добавления 'c' до такой строчки "func.min(uploads.c.timestamp)" пока не знаю почему . Буду вникать

Comment: Да, все верно, поля таблицы доступны через свойство `.c`. Это я ошибся.

Comment: Я удовлетворился таким запросом `db.session.query(uploads, func.min(uploads.c.timestamp)).filter_by(file_id=1).first()`. Возвращает сущность где доступны `file_id`, `user_id`, `timestamp` и второй запрос делать нет нужды

Comment: О, ну так конечно лучше, раз работает :)